# How does Tor pass the router?

Tags: security, firewall

Here's the story.

> When I run Tor software, in theory my computer becomes a *relay*, so
>   **user x** sends some data to **my computer** and **my computer** passes
>   that data to **user y** and vice versa.

This is achieved by **user x** calling ***my IP address*** (for example 123.123.123.123) and sending something to the Tor software running on my system. But it's not possible! My ADSL router doesn't allow traffics to go directly to my local IP address (for example 192.168.1.5). Instead it shows an error page or something (default firewall policies of all known brands!)

And if so, how does my router knows which local IP address to pass the incoming data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run Tor software, in theory my computer becomes a relay

Not by default.

You have to purposefully configure the Tor software to be a relay. And if you're doing that, you hopefully know how to configure your router to forward a port to your computer so you can run a relay on it.